# Javascript: Possible to get newlines?

Tags: javascript, dom

My code is something like this:

```
function attr(el, attr, value) 
{
    el.setAttribute(attr, value);
}

    var f2=document.createElement("form");
        attr(f2, 'id', "det_"+tresult_no);
        attr(f2, 'name', "form"+tresult_no);

   var t2=document.createElement("TABLE");
    attr(t2, 'width', 80);
    attr(t2, 'border', 0);
f2.appendChild(t2);
```

then to see/confirm what I am doing is right, I do this:

```
document.getElementById('testing').value=t.innerHTML;
```

where "testing" is a textarea.
This works out pretty well... except  with a lot of code, the textarea gets filled up and is abit hard to read.

Is there anyway to get some line breaks in the textarea after everytime I add one object to another?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider using *Firebug*? The `log` `Function` of the `console` `Object` will print a new line whenever it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the "testing" object is an input or textarea field that displays text and newlines, how about something like this?

```
document.getElementById('testing').value=t.innerHTML.replace(">", ">\n");
```

or to just target a newline after closing tags:

```
document.getElementById("result").value = html.replace(/<\/[^>]+?>/g, "$&\n");
```

Note, this isn't a perfect regex for matching closing HTML tags, but for the purposes of debugging, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
document.getElementById('testing').value= '<br/>' + t.innerHTML;
```

This start each addition on a new line.